# Can someone help me replace the **for loop** to **while loop** I'm struggling to figure it out?

Tags: python, computer-science

Can someone help me replace the **for loop** to **while loop** I'm struggling to figure it out?

The question specifically asks us not to use for loop. That's why I need to replace it with the **while loop**

I have listed below:

1. my code
2. Sample testing of the **input** and the **output**
3. the conditions we have to follow:

```
 def matrix_equal(matrix1, matrix2):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Compares two matrices to see if they are equal - i.e. have the
    same contents in the same locations.
    Use: equal = matrix_equal(matrix1, matrix2)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        matrix1 - the first matrix (2D list of ?)
        matrix2 - the second matrix (2D list of ?)
    Returns:
        equal - True if matrix1 and matrix2 are equal,
            False otherwise (boolean)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    """
    equal = True
    if((len(matrix1) != len(matrix2)) or (len(matrix1[0]) != len(matrix2[0]))):
        equal = False
    for x in range(len(matrix1)):
        if(equal == False):
            break
        for y in range(len(matrix1[0])):
            num1 = matrix1[x][y]
            num2 = matrix2[x][y]
            if(num1 != num2):
                equal = False
                break
    return equal
```

**Sample testing:**

```
First matrix:
      0    1    2
 0    c    a    t
 1    d    o    g
 2    b    i    g

Second matrix:
      0    1    2
 0    c    a    t
 1    d    o    g
 2    b    i    g

Equal matrices: True
```

**The conditions we have to follow:**

```
1. should not call input in the function
2. should not call print in the function
3. should not have multiple returns
```

Comment: This looks like homework, so I don't want to post a more complete solution. But here's the general idea. `for` takes care of creating a predefined iterator and iterating over the items in it. `while` is "dumb", it only checks for a logical condition, and it will keep looping until the condition fails. It does not create the iterator of items and it does not automatically advance to the next item. You have to do all those thing manually, including making sure you use a condition that will eventually evaluate to `False`, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, this is a solution using while loop :

```
def matrix_equal(mat1,mat2):
  equal = True
  if(len(mat1[0]) == len(mat2[0]) and len(mat1) == len(mat2)):
    i = 0
    n = len(mat1[0])
    m = len(mat1)
    while(i < m):
      j = 0
      while(j < n):
        if(mat1[i][j] != mat2[i][j]):
          equal = False
          break
        j+=1
      if(equal==False):
        break
      i+=1
  else:
        equal = False
  return equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for x in range(len(matrix1)):
```

to

```
x = 0
while x < len(matrix1):
    x += 1
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can transform :

```
for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
  {do stuff...}
```

into

```
i = 0
while i < mat.shape[0]:
  {do stuff...}
  # increment i with 1
  i += 1
```

so here you would get :

```
def mat_eq_while(matrix1, matrix2):
  i = 0
  j = 0
  equal = True
  if(not (mat1.shape == mat2.shape) ):
      equal = False
  while i < mat1.shape[0]:
      if(equal == False):
          break
      while j < mat1.shape[1]:
          num1 = matrix1[i, j]
          num2 = matrix2[i, j]
          if(num1 != num2):
              equal = False
              break
          j += 1
      i += 1
  return equal
```

test it with

```
import numpy as np
mat1 = np.matrix(range(9)).reshape(3,3)
mat2 = np.matrix(range(1, 10)).reshape(3,3)

print( mat_eq_while(mat1, mat1) )
print( mat_eq_while(mat1, mat2) )
```